# Android app crashes when I implement onclicklistener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I´m getting an error always when I try to implement an onClickListener.

There is my code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

and here is my XML code:
    
LogCat

```
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667): Process: com.gonzalo.ejemplo, PID: 19667
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gonzalo.ejemplo/com.gonzalo.ejemplo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at com.gonzalo.ejemplo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
06-07 02:54:05.901: E/AndroidRuntime(19667):    ... 11 more
06-07 02:59:05.974: I/Process(19667): Sending signal. PID: 19667 SIG: 9
```

so.. any idea how can I fix it??

Thanks

Comment: My guess is you are using the latest ADT and have created a new project which has a `Fragment` in it. In that case the `Button` will be in your fragment XML file and not the activity one. You need to move the `Button` code into your `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById` is probably returning null. Make sure there is a Button in your layout with `android:id="@+id/btn_submit"`.

Answer (score 1):

This Variable could be the problem.

```
Button btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
```

Check in your `activity_main.xml` if exist `btn_submit`, maybe has another name.

Comment: Thanks, I have confused the activity, that's the reason return me a null.